# How to fix shutter release disabled

Tags: shutter-release, nikon-d5500

I have a Nikon D5500
It has a message Shutter release disabled
How do I fix this please

Comment: Do you have your battery charged? Try to remove the battery and put it again in to the camera.

Comment: The user manual indicates that the screen should additionally say "Recharge battery". Do you also have this text on your screen?

Answer (score 1):

It's a battery issue. Either recharge or replace the battery.

From the D5500 reference manual

[image]